# How to use thumb-2 instructions with GCC

Tags: gcc, assembly, compilation, thumb

I have written the following simplistic memcpy32 function, as a means of understanding how to write assembly code for the cortex-m4.

```
    .section .text
    .align 2
    .global as_memcpy32
    .type as_memcpy32, %function
as_memcpy32:
     push    {r4, lr}
     movs    r3, #0
start_loop: 
     cmp     r3, r2
     bge   end_loop
     ldr   r4, [r1]
     str   r4, [r0]
     add   r0, #4
     add   r1, #4
     add    r3, #1
     b     start_loop
end_loop:   
    pop     {r4, pc}
```

The above code compiles and runs. These are only 16bit instructions. I want to use 32 bit thumb2 instructions also as they are supported by the Cortex-M4. And the main point of writing assembly is to run my code faster.

I should be able to use the following form of the ldr and str instruction according to the STM32F4 manual

```
op{type}{cond} Rt, [Rn], #offset; post-indexed
```

I am supplying the following options to the GCC.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc" -c -g -x assembler-with-cpp -MMD -mcpu=cortex-m4 -DF_CPU=168000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_STM32DiscoveryF407 -DARDUINO_ARCH_STM32F4  -DMCU_STM32F406VG -mthumb -DSTM32_HIGH_DENSITY -DSTM32F2 -DSTM32F4 -DBOARD_discovery_f4   -mthumb -D__STM32F4__ memcpy.S" -o memcpy.S.o
```

When I try to use the following instructions for ldr and str

```
ldr r4, [r1], #4
ldr r4, [r0], #4
```

I get the following errors.

```
memcpy.S: Assembler messages:

memcpy.S:11: Error: Thumb does not support this addressing mode -- `ldr r4,[r1],#4'

memcpy.S:12: Error: Thumb does not support this addressing mode -- `str r4,[r0],#4'

exit status 1
Error compiling for board STM32 Discovery F407.
```

I am not able to understand what the problem is. Actually the compiler itself generated a lot more complex addressing opcode.

```
ldr.w   r4, [r1, r3, lsl #2]
str.w   r4, [r0, r3, lsl #2]
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just found that I should say

```
.syntax unified
```

below

```
.section
```

The following topic deals with other things, but I saw it there and tried. It worked.

[How to generate the machine code of Thumb instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720488/how-to-generate-the-machine-code-of-thumb-instructions?rq=1)

Comment: `.syntax unified` can be the first line of your source file.  [The directive applies globally](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html), not just within a section.

Comment: So if I use `-mthumb` parameter at assemble time GNU assembler only alows Thumb16 instructions to be assembled but `.syntax unified` directive tells assembler it can also include Thumb32 instructions in the final assembly?